# How can I setup a VPN like connection using an intermediary server?

Tags: vpn

I need to connect two computers on separate networks over a VPN.  Both routers the computers are behind block any incoming connections.  Hamachi is able to connect the computers but it uses a slow speed relay connection.  Since I already have a server, rather than paying for a high speed relay with hamachi, is there some other VPN software that I can use that is relatively easy to setup or at least has good instructions?

Edit: Both computers are running Windows Vista (one is 32 bit, the other 64 bit)

Comment: what OS are the two computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN would be a good choice for this. Set an external server as the VPN server, and configure the two machines as clients, and you should be good to go.

However, setting up OpenVPN on x64 is a little tricky. Might need to do some googling there.

Comment: We'll I finally got openvpn setup on the server and both clients are able to connect to it but I cant get the clients to connect to each other.  I'm not sure what I have to do now

Comment: Are you having them connect to each other via the VPN addresses? Do they have software firewalls blocking the VPN IPs? What are you using to test these connections?

Comment: I set the client-to-client option on the server and tried pinging the IP of the server and the client from each client.  The ping only reaches the server.  Firewalls on both computers were disabled.  Are there any push rules I'm supposed to set?

Comment: No, however ICMP traffic may not be running through the VPN properly. Can you set up some sort of other network service, like a LAN game, and see if that connects?

Comment: I tried that with no success.  I noticed that OpenVPN says the IP of the computer is 10.8.0.8 but then when I look at the details of the adapter itself, it lists a different IP and subnet mask.  It doesn't even start with 10.8.0.X.  Any idea what would cause this?  Both clients have identical config files

Comment: Which adaptor are you looking at, the network adaptor, or the TUN or TAP adaptor that VNC installed?

Comment: The one that OpenVPN installed.  It says on the description TAP-WIN32 Adapter V9

Comment: I dont know why but for some reason it started working now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vista has [its own VPN system built in](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Vista/PPTP/PPTPVPN.html) apparently, so it might be a good bet